# Is there a way to allow negative decimals for TextField in Jetpack Compose on all Android versions?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I'm trying to use an OutlinedTextField that allows both negative & positive decimal numbers.
Currently, I have this code to change the keyboard type:

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal, imeAction = ImeAction.Next)
```

But this only allows positive numbers decimals as you can see here:

[image: keyboard without negative sign]

I feel like I must be blind or something because I can't find this trivial thing. I've seen answers on SO where the negative sign is present when they use Number, but this is not the case for me.

**EDIT:** Inspired by Gabriele, I did some tests on multiple Android versions and saw that it's not consistent. With Android 5.1.1 & 9 it's not present, while it is present on Android 13. Does anyone know how to force it on all versions?

Comment: The negative sign should be present with KeyboardType.Decimal (at least I have it).

Comment: What is the compose version you're using? I'm at 1.2.1

Comment: Tried with 1.3.1

Comment: Can I also ask what Android version you're using? I did tests on multiple devices and had different results. On 5.1.1 & 9 I don't get the negative sign. On my device with 13 I have the negative sign

Comment: Android 11-12-13

Comment: Sorry, can I ask one more question? Do you happen to use GBoard on those 3 devices?

Comment: With an emulator do you have the same issue?

Comment: No, but the emulators use Gboard by default afaik. The devices (all Samsung devices) that had this problem no longer have the issue once I installed Gboard on it.